# What does Monokuma's Morse code theatre translate to?

Tags: danganronpa

I've been playing Dangan Ronpa 2 and one of the Monokuma theaters that act as short intervals was done in Morse code.

What does it mean?

[image: -... . / ... ..- .-. . / - --- / -.. .-. .. -. -.- / -.-- --- ..- .-. / -.- ..- -- .- - .. -. .]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typing it out and using a tool to translate it reveals the message:

> **BE SURE TO DRINK YOUR KUMATINE**

Mysterious.

This is in fact a reference to [*A Christmas Story*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Christmas_Story), in which the protagonist Ralphie gets his decoder ring and feverishly tries to decode the radio's message. The message turns out to be "Be sure to drink your Ovaltine" - a very disappointing advertisement, rather than the 'spy' message he was hoping to obtain.

> "Ovaltine? A crummy commercial? Son of a bitch! "

Kuma is Japanese for Bear (Mono kuma - Mono Bear), which is where that part of the message comes from.